# jQuery event handler does not trigger on consecutive clicks on a Bootstrap dropdown toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever a user opens a dropdown I should populate it from a database:

To do this I thought I'd register an event handler for the button that opens the dropdown:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.schedulesDropdown', function() {
  alert("call api with ajax and populate dropdown with result")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle schedulesDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  stuff
</div>
```

The issue is that it is only triggered once.

If I remove bootstrap it works like a charm:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.schedulesDropdown', function() {
  alert("call api with ajax and populate dropdown with result")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle schedulesDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  stuff
</div>
```

Since the problem is with bootstrap I don't know what the next step is.

Comment: Without seeing full code, it's impossible to say what the issue it. Your current code should work fine

Comment: What more parts should i include? @SagarV

Comment: try to create a page with static values instead of fetching from db, add it here or use a fiddle

Comment: @SagarV I am not getting anything from db yet, the comments are just to show my intention. I should have been clearer.

Comment: I've removed the `ajax` tag since you're saying that it's not actually doing any ajax. I've also put your code into a "Stack Snippet". I run that in Chrome and clicking on the button twice shows the alert twice. There is likely other code that is interfering. From the CSS class names, it appears as though you're using Bootstrap, which could be where the problem is, since it does things to the HTML.

Comment: I added the bootstrap cdn links and the problem is seen in the snippet @HereticMonkey

Comment: Cool, yeah, I'm not a Bootstrap expert, but it could be that its code stops propagation of the click event when it binds, so the first one works, then the Bootstrap code takes over. I don't know that for a fact, so I'm not answering :). Good luck!

Comment: @HereticMonkey hmm okay, well thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onclick event instead accessing it through DOM and pass **this** keyword as argument to the method called in event. `<button onclick=“return methodName(this)” >`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I use jquery for everything else though, so my code would not be concistent but it doesn't matter that much.